# How to show a Focus Ring around NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, focus, nstextfield, nstextview

I have a NSTextView added to my view via interface builder.
If I run my application, no focus ring is shown around the TextView if the TextView is focused (for example while editing text). I would like to have a focus ring like on any other NSTextField.

[image: focus ring missing]

Comment: Did you try the focus ring setting in IB?

Comment: The focus ring setting is set to Default for the ScrollView, ClipView and TextView. Should be ok?

Comment: Apparently the default is no focus ring, is this what you want?

Comment: @Willeke Thank you so much! This actually helped. I though "Default" always means, that the focus ring is displayed, didn't know that some components do not show focus rings by default.